# a singular for "unwashed-masses"

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

What is a derogatory adjective in singular form, to address to someone from the countryside, a single person, as opposite to the idiom **"unwashed-masses"** that would require a more elaborate construction, e.g. "You are part of the unwashed-masses" or similarly.

Surely I do not need it to offend a real person, I assure you! It is a character in a short story, and the one who is meant to use this line is the bad guy, thereby I do not consider people from countryside "unwashed". I grew up in the countryside myself. :))

Could I use simply **"unwashed"** with the same meaning/effect? e.g. "You unwashed... something..."

I did search Thesaurus and other dictionaries, only that they don't tell me much in particular.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use *unwashed* on its own, but [*unkempt*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unkempt) might be better.

Comment: Thanks! I did eventually use **unwashed**, waiting for confirmation. Your answer settled it. :)

Comment: I usually go with *scruffy-looking nerf-herder*.

Comment: You know, **unkempt** proved a better choice than **unwashed**, after a couple of rereads. It sounds classier. I also took note of these last two. I deeply appreciate! You helped me a lot!